# Cross cluster communication in GKE Multi-cluster Service

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, redpanda

I’m using GKE multi-cluster service and have configured two clusters.

On one cluster I have an endpoint I want to consume and it's **hard-coded** on address:

`redpanda-0.redpanda.processing.svc.cluster.local.`

Does anyone know how I can reach this from the other cluster?

###### EDIT:

I have exported the service, which is then automatically imported into the other cluster. Previously, I have been able to connect to the other cluster using `SERVICE_EXPORT_NAME.NAMESPACE.svc.clusterset.local`, but then I had to change the endpoint address manually to this exact address. In my new case, the endpoint address is not configurable.

Comment: Have you configured the ServiceExport(s)?  See https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/multi-cluster-services#registering_a_service_for_export.  Once you've done that, your service should be available across all clusters via SERVICE_EXPORT_NAME.NAMESPACE.svc.clusterset.local

Comment: Yes, I have @GariSingh! But if the endpoint address I want to connect to is hard-coded to something other than SERVICE_EXPORT_NAME.NAMESPACE.svc.clusterset.local, will this still be true?

Comment: Previously, I've been able to connect across clusters using the address you posted before by manually changing the endpoint address to the address you posted. But in this case, I can't edit the endpoint address I want to connect to. It is hardcoded to the one I posted in my question, without "clusterset" in it.